# Calculate the volume of $S^n(1)$

Tags: integration, analysis

I use $S^{n}(1)$ to denote the spherical shell in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and $B^{n}(1)$ to be solid ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$

In $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ ,I want to calculate the volume of $S^n(1)$ which is the "sphereical shell" of $n+1$ dimensional sphere. I think the "volume" of $S^n(1)$ should be considered in $\mathbb{R}^n$ , just like $S^2$ doesn't have so-called "volume" in $\mathbb{R}^3$, its "volume" is "area" in $\mathbb{R}^2$
My first attempt was to calculate the area of $S^2$ , the integration is $$\begin{align*}
\int_{S^2(1)} 1 \ d \sigma =\int_{S^1(1)} 1 \ d \sigma \cdot \int_{-1}^1 1 \ dz=2\pi \cdot2=4\pi  &&(1)
\end{align*}$$I use $d \sigma$ to denote the integration with respect to volume.

I notice that when I separate the integral into 2 parts (since function $1$ is continuous, we can use the Fubini theorem.), the first part is the "volume" of $S^1(1)$ which is the perimeter of it, but the latter part is integral on $B^1(1)$ since by definition $$\begin{align*}
B^1{(1)}=\{x:|x|<1\}
\end{align*}$$ so integrate from $-1$ to $1$ is just integrate on $B^1(1)$ . Thus, I think $(1)$ can be written as $$\begin{align*}
\int_{S^2(1)}1 \ d \sigma &= \int_{S^1(1)} 1 \ d \sigma \cdot \int_{B^1(1)} 1 \ d \sigma
\end{align*}$$ Is this true if I generalize this into $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ ? That is, is $$\begin{align*}
\int_{S^n(1)} 1 \ d \sigma &= \int_{S^1(1)} \ 1 \ d \sigma \cdot \int_{B^{n-1}(1)}1 \ d \sigma
\end{align*}$$ true? If this is true, how should I explain that the integration on $S^{n}$ can be "separated" into the integration on $S^1$ and $B^{n-1}$? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your conjecture $|S^n(1)|=|S_1(1)||B^{n-1}(1)|=2\pi|B^{n-1}(1)|$ is true, as you can verify from the [closed-forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_sphere#General_area_and_volume_formulas) $|S^{n-1}(R)|=\frac{2\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}R^{n-1}$ and $|B^{n}(R)|=\frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(1+n/2)}R^n$. If you want to make your reasoning more precise, you might want to introduce coordinate systems for your integrals, and try to show the relationship from there.

Comment: As far as I could follow, you try to make sense on hyperspheres. They an $n$-nhypersphere has a volume in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and an equivalent area in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. This area is called a _form_. You must be familiar with Stokes' theorem. In case you are not, I recommend this book: https://people.ucsc.edu/~rmont/papers/Burke_DivGradCurl.pdf